# How do I grab all the unique values in a fetch request?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, fetch

```js
async function fetchTemplates() {
    let seturl = `https://wax.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/templates?collection_name=mlb.topps&schema_name=series1}&has_assets=true&page=1&limit=3414&order=desc&sort=created`;
    
    try {
        let res = await fetch(seturl);
        return await res.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

}

async function renderFilterVariants(arg) {
    let sets = await fetchTemplates();
    console.log(sets);

    if( !Array.isArray( sets.data ) )
    {
        throw new Error( "atts.data is not an array." );
    }

    const team  = sets.data.map( d => d.immutable_data.${arg});
    console.log(team);
    
}

renderFilterVariants(cardid);
```

Why doesn't this work? I want the function to be able to pass a custom variation under d.immutable_data

[image]

It has to be dynamic as the variations under immutable_data is different depending on page.

[image]

Comment: I feel like your question could have been 5 times shorter.

Comment: @RoboRobok question updated with new code, does that make it easier for you to answer? thanks a lot!

Comment: But where's `cardid`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your line
`const team  = sets.data.map( d => d.immutable_data.${arg});`
In order to get into an object key using a parameter (like arg) you shouldn't use a dot (in your code - `.${arg}`) but with brackets [ ] .

**Example**

Say you have an object foo.
`foo = { bar: 5}`
In order to get the key 'bar' inside 'foo' you can do both:
`foo.bar`
or
`foo['bar']`

**Meaning**

In you code you should write :
`const team  = sets.data.map( d => d.immutable_data[arg]);`

again this cause since `arg` (your variable) is a string, and when you using a string to get key in javascript object you should use brackets.

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue that i've commonly been getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'"

Comment: I found the problem, i edited the answer. In order to use string literal (${string}) you should use back tics:  `${string}`. In this case you don't need it. Just use : `d.immutable_data[arg]`

Comment: @J.De did this solve your problem? If so, consider accepting the answer. If not, consider adding a comment or updating your question to further clarify your question.